# Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a "char *s" initialized with a string literal, but not "char s[]"?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c-strings

The following code receives seg fault on line 2:

```
char *str = "string";
str[0] = 'z';  // could be also written as *str = 'z'
printf("%s\n", str);
```

While this works perfectly well:

```
char str[] = "string";
str[0] = 'z';
printf("%s\n", str);
```

Tested with MSVC and GCC.

Comment: Its funny - but this actually compiles and runs perfectly when using windows compiler (cl) on a visual studio developer command prompt. Got me confused for a few moments...

Answer (score 283, accepted):

See the C FAQ, [Question 1.32](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html)

> **Q**: What is the difference between these initializations?
>   `char a[] = "string literal";`
>   `char *p  = "string literal";`
>   My program crashes if I try to assign a new value to `p[i]`.
>
> **A**: A string literal (the formal term
>   for a double-quoted string in C
>   source) can be used in two slightly
>   different ways:
>
> 1. As the initializer for an array of char, as in the declaration of `char a[]` , it specifies the initial values
>      of the characters in that array (and,
>      if necessary, its size).
> 2. Anywhere else, it turns into an unnamed, static array of characters,
>      and this unnamed array may be stored
>      in read-only memory, and which
>      therefore cannot necessarily be
>      modified. In an expression context,
>      the array is converted at once to a
>      pointer, as usual (see section 6), so
>      the second declaration initializes p
>      to point to the unnamed array's first
>      element.
>
> Some compilers have a switch
>   controlling whether string literals
>   are writable or not (for compiling old
>   code), and some may have options to
>   cause string literals to be formally
>   treated as arrays of const char (for
>   better error catching).

Comment: Couple of other points: (1) the segfault happens as described, but its occurrence is a function of the run environment; if the same code was in an embedded system, the write may have no effect, or it may actually change the s to a z. (2) Because string literals are non-writable, the compiler can save space by putting two instances of "string" in the same place; or, if somewhere else in the code you have "another string", then one chunk of memory could support both literals. Clearly, if code were then allowed to change those bytes, strange and difficult bugs could occur.

Comment: @greggo: Good point. There is also a way to do this on systems with MMU by using `mprotect` to wave read-only protection (see [here](http://lazarenko.me/2013/05/01/how-constant-is-a-constant/)).

Comment: So char *p="blah" actually creates a temporary array ?weird.

Comment: And after 2 years of writing in C++...TIL

Comment: @rahultyagi  what do you mean ?

Comment: @rahul tyagi, Not a temporary array. Quite the opposite, it's the longest lived of arrays. It's created by the compiler and found in the executable file itself. What you should have understood from the above is that It's a *shared* array that must be treated as *read-only* (and may actually be read-only).

Answer (score 121):

Normally, string literals are stored in read-only memory when the program is run. This is to prevent you from accidentally changing a string constant. In your first example, `"string"` is stored in read-only memory and `*str` points to the first character. The segfault happens when you try to change the first character to `'z'`.

In the second example, the string `"string"` is *copied* by the compiler from its read-only home to the `str[]` array. Then changing the first character is permitted. You can check this by printing the address of each:

```
printf("%p", str);
```

Also, printing the size of `str` in the second example will show you that the compiler has allocated 7 bytes for it:

```
printf("%d", sizeof(str));
```

Comment: Whenever using "%p" on printf, you should cast the pointer to void * as in printf("%p", (void *)str);
When printing a size_t with printf, you should use "%zu" if using the latest C standard (C99).

Comment: Also, the parenthesis with sizeof are only needed when taking the size of a type (the argument then looks like a cast). Remember that sizeof is an operator, not a function.

Comment: and [use `%zu` to print `size_t`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714)

Comment: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=] :/

Answer (score 47):

Most of these answers are correct, but just to add a little more clarity...

The "read only memory" that people are referring to is the text segment in ASM terms. It's the same place in memory where the instructions are loaded. This is read-only for obvious reasons like security. When you create a char* initialized to a string, the string data is compiled into the text segment and the program initializes the pointer to point into the text segment. So if you try to change it, kaboom. Segfault.

When written as an array, the compiler places the initialized string data in the data segment instead, which is the same place that your global variables and such live. This memory is mutable, since there are no instructions in the data segment. This time when the compiler initializes the character array (which is still just a char*) it's pointing into the data segment rather than the text segment, which you can safely alter at run-time.

Comment: But isn't it true that there can be implementations that allow modifying the "read-only memory"?

Comment: When written as an array, the compiler places the initialized string data in the data segment if they are static or global. Otherwise (e.g. for a normal automatic array) it places on the stack, in the stack frame of the function main. Correct?

Comment: @SE Yeah, I would imagine that Bob Somers is referring to both the stack, heap and static (including static and global variables) when writing "the data segment". And a local array is put on the stack, so you're correct there :)

Comment: Sorry, but you are probably correct here, The data segment is the part of the memory dedicated for initialized global or static variables, but the array could also be put on the stack if it is local, as you've written.

Comment: @Pacerier There are. If this was code from a floppy disk on an 8-bit micro you could absolutely modify it. It's "read-only" in the RWX flag sense, not a RAM vs. ROM sense.

Answer (score 37):

> Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?

**C99 N1256 draft**

There are two different uses of character string literals:

1. Initialize `char[]`:

   ```
   char c[] = "abc";
   ```

   This is "more magic", and described at 6.7.8/14 "Initialization":

   > An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally
   >   enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the
   >   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
   >   elements of the array.

   So this is just a shortcut for:

   ```
   char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
   ```

   Like any other regular array, `c` can be modified.
2. Everywhere else: it generates an:

   - unnamed
   - array of char [What is the type of string literals in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245664/what-is-the-type-of-string-literals-in-c-c)
   - with static storage
   - that gives UB if modified

   So when you write:

   ```
   char *c = "abc";
   ```

   This is similar to:

   ```
   /* __unnamed is magic because modifying it gives UB. */
   static char __unnamed[] = "abc";
   char *c = __unnamed;
   ```

   Note the implicit cast from `char[]` to `char *`, which is always legal.

   Then if you modify `c[0]`, you also modify `__unnamed`, which is UB.

   This is documented at 6.4.5 "String literals":

   > 5 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
   >   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. The multibyte character
   >   sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
   >   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
   >   type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
   >   sequence [...]
   >
   > 6 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
   >   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
   >   undefined.

6.7.8/32 "Initialization" gives a direct example:

> EXAMPLE 8: The declaration
>
> ```
> char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines "plain" char array objects `s` and `t` whose elements are initialized with character string literals.
>
> This declaration is identical to
>
> ```
> char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
> t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
> ```
>
> The contents of the arrays are modifiable. On the other hand, the declaration
>
> ```
> char *p = "abc";
> ```
>
> defines `p` with type "pointer to char" and initializes it to point to an object with type "array of char" with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. If an attempt is made to use `p` to modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined.

**GCC 4.8 x86-64 ELF implementation**

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *s = "abc";
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and decompile:

```
gcc -ggdb -std=c99 -c main.c
objdump -Sr main.o
```

Output contains:

```
 char *s = "abc";
8:  48 c7 45 f8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
f:  00 
        c: R_X86_64_32S .rodata
```

Conclusion: GCC stores `char*` it in `.rodata` section, not in `.text`.

If we do the same for `char[]`:

```
 char s[] = "abc";
```

we obtain:

```
17:   c7 45 f0 61 62 63 00    movl   $0x636261,-0x10(%rbp)
```

so it gets stored in the stack (relative to `%rbp`).

Note however that the default linker script puts `.rodata` and `.text` in the same segment, which has execute but no write permission. This can be observed with:

```
readelf -l a.out
```

which contains:

```
 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   02     .text .rodata
```

Comment: So in other words the string is so short that in our case the bytes were interpreted as an `int` and pushed onto the stack that way.

Comment: @puppydrum64 it's not linked to string size. One must always go on stack (because it can be modified according to C standard). The other could go on stack or text, but text is more efficient (as you don't need to keep loading new copies on every function call).

Answer (score 19):

In the first code, "string" is a string constant, and string constants should never be modified because they are often placed into read only memory.  "str" is a pointer being used to modify the constant.

In the second code, "string" is an array initializer, sort of short hand for

```
char str[7] =  { 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0' };
```

"str" is an array allocated on the stack and can be modified freely.

Comment: On the stack, or the data segment if `str` is global or `static`.

Answer (score 13):

Because the type of `"whatever"` in the context of the 1st example is `const char *` (even if you assign it to a non-const char*), which means you shouldn't try and write to it.

The compiler has enforced this by putting the string in a read-only part of memory, hence writing to it generates a segfault.

Answer (score 9):

```
char *str = "string";
```

The above sets `str` to point to the literal value `"string"` which is hard-coded in the program's binary image, which is probably flagged as read-only in memory.

So `str[0]=` is attempting to write to the read-only code of the application.  I would guess this is probably compiler dependent though.

Answer (score 8):

To understand this error or problem you should first know difference b/w the pointer and array
so here firstly i have explain you differences b/w them

#### string array

```
 char strarray[] = "hello";
```

In memory array is stored in continuous memory cells, stored as `[h][e][l][l][o][\0] =>[]` is 1 char byte size memory cell ,and this continuous memory cells can be access by name named strarray here.so here string array `strarray` itself containing all characters of string initialized to it.in this case here `"hello"`
so we can easily change its memory content by accessing each character by its index value

```
`strarray[0]='m'` it access character at index 0 which is 'h'in strarray
```

and its value changed to `'m'` so strarray value changed to `"mello"`;

one point to note here that we can change the content of string array by changing character by character but can not initialized other string directly to it like `strarray="new string"` is invalid

#### Pointer

As we all know  pointer points to memory location in memory ,
uninitialized pointer points to random memory location so and after initialization points to particular memory location

```
char *ptr = "hello";
```

here pointer ptr is initialized to string `"hello"` which is  constant string stored in read only memory (ROM) so `"hello"` can not be changed as it is stored in ROM

and ptr is stored in stack section and pointing to constant string `"hello"`

so ptr[0]='m' is invalid since you can not access read only memory

But ptr can be initialised to other string value directly since it is just pointer so it can be point to any memory address of variable of its data type

```
ptr="new string"; is valid
```

Answer (score 7):

```
char *str = "string";
```

allocates a pointer to a string literal, which the compiler is putting in a non-modifiable part of your executable;

```
char str[] = "string";
```

allocates and initializes a local array which is modifiable

Comment: can we write `int *b = {1,2,3)`  like we write `char *s = "HelloWorld"` ?

Comment: @SurajJain no, we can't do that, because it will be invalid conversion ( int to int* ). also we cant write ```char* ptr = { 'a', 'b'};``` that will also be invalid conversion( char to char*).

Answer (score 6):

The C FAQ that @matli linked to mentions it, but no one else here has yet, so for clarification: if a string literal (double-quoted string in your source) is used anywhere *other than* to initialize a character array (ie: @Mark's second example, which works correctly), that string is stored by the compiler in a special *static string table*, which is akin to creating a global static variable (read-only, of course) that is essentially anonymous (has no variable "name"). The *read-only* part is the important part, and is why the @Mark's first code example segfaults.

Comment: can we write `int *b = {1,2,3)`  like we write `char *s = "HelloWorld"` ?

Answer (score 4):

The

```
 char *str = "string";
```

line defines a pointer and points it to a literal string.  The literal string is not writable so when you do:

```
  str[0] = 'z';
```

you get a seg fault.  On some platforms, the literal might be in writable memory so you won't see a segfault, but it's invalid code (resulting in undefined behavior) regardless.

The line:

```
char str[] = "string";
```

allocates an array of characters and **copies** the literal string into that array, which is fully writable, so the subsequent update is no problem.

Comment: can we write `int *b = {1,2,3)`  like we write `char *s = "HelloWorld"` ?

Answer (score 3):

String literals like "string" are probably allocated in your executable's address space as read-only data (give or take your compiler).  When you go to touch it, it freaks out that you're in its bathing suit area and lets you know with a seg fault.

In your first example, you're getting a pointer to that const data.  In your second example, you're initializing an array of 7 characters with a copy of the const data.

Answer (score 2):

```
// create a string constant like this - will be read only
char *str_p;
str_p = "String constant";

// create an array of characters like this 
char *arr_p;
char arr[] = "String in an array";
arr_p = &arr[0];

// now we try to change a character in the array first, this will work
*arr_p = 'E';

// lets try to change the first character of the string contant
*str_p = 'G'; // this will result in a segmentation fault. Comment it out to work.


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  String constants can't be modified. A segmentation fault is the result,
 *  because most operating systems will not allow a write
 *  operation on read only memory.
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

//print both strings to see if they have changed
printf("%s\n", str_p); //print the string without a variable
printf("%s\n", arr_p); //print the string, which is in an array.
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Constant memory

Since string literals are read-only by design, they are stored in the **Constant part** of memory. Data stored there is immutable, i.e., cannot be changed. Thus, all string literals defined in C code get a read-only memory address here.

#### Stack memory

The **Stack part** of memory is where the addresses of local variables live, e.g., variables defined in functions.

---

As @matli's answer suggests, there are two ways of working with string these constant strings.

#### 1. Pointer to string literal

When we define a pointer to a string literal, we are creating a pointer variable living in **Stack memory**. It points to the read-only address where the underlying string literal resides.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char *s = "hello";
  printf("%p\n", &s);  // Prints a read-only address, e.g. 0x7ffc8e224620
  return 0;
}
```

If we try to modify `s` by inserting

```c
s[0] = 'H';
```

we get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. We are trying to access memory that we shouldn't access. We are attempting to modify the value of a read-only address, `0x7ffc8e224620`.

#### 2. Array of chars

For the sake of the example, suppose the string literal `"Hello"` stored in constant memory has a read-only memory address identical to the one above, `0x7ffc8e224620`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  // We create an array from a string literal with address 0x7ffc8e224620.
  // C initializes an array variable in the stack, let's give it address
  // 0x7ffc7a9a9db2.
  // C then copies the read-only value from 0x7ffc8e224620 into 
  // 0x7ffc7a9a9db2 to give us a local copy we can mutate.
  char a[] = "hello";

  // We can now mutate the local copy
  a[0] = 'H';

  printf("%p\n", &a);  // Prints the Stack address, e.g. 0x7ffc7a9a9db2
  printf("%s\n", a);   // Prints "Hello"

  return 0;
}
```

---

> **Note:** When using pointers to string literals as in 1., best practice is to use the `const` keyword, like `const *s = "hello"`. This is more readable and the compiler will provide better help when it's violated. It will then throw an error like `error: assignment of read-only location ‘*s’` instead of the seg fault. Linters in editors will also likely pick up the error before you manually compile the code.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, `str` is a pointer that points at `"string"`.  The compiler is allowed to put string literals in places in memory that you cannot write to, but can only read.  (This really should have triggered a warning, since you're assigning a `const char *` to a `char *`.  Did you have warnings disabled, or did you just ignore them?)

In the second place, you're creating an array, which is memory that you've got full access to, and initializing it with `"string"`.  You're creating a `char[7]` (six for the letters, one for the terminating '\0'), and you do whatever you like with it.

Comment: @Ferruccio, ? Yes `const` prefix make variables Read-Only

Comment: In C string literals have type `char [N]`, not `const char [N]`, so there is no warning. (You can change that in gcc at least by passing `-Wwrite-strings`.)

Answer (score 1):

Assume the strings are,

```
char a[] = "string literal copied to stack";
char *p  = "string literal referenced by p";
```

In the first case, the literal is to be copied when 'a' comes into scope. Here 'a' is an array defined on stack. It means the string will be created on the stack and its data is copied from code (text) memory, which is typically read-only (this is implementation specific, a compiler can place this read-only program data in read-writable memory also).

In the second case, p is a pointer defined on stack (local scope) and referring a string literal (program data or text) stored else where. Usually modifying such memory is not good practice nor encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

`Section 5.5 Character Pointers and Functions` of `K&R` also discusses about this topic:

> There is an important difference between these definitions:
>
> `char amessage[] = "now is the time"; /* an array */`
> `char *pmessage = "now is the time"; /* a pointer */`
>
> `amessage` is an array, just big enough to hold the sequence of characters and `'\0'` that initializes it. Individual characters within the array may be changed but `amessage` will always refer to the same storage. On the other hand, `pmessage` is a pointer, initialized to point to a string constant; the pointer may subsequently be modified to point elsewhere, but the result is undefined if you try to modify the string contents.

Answer (score 0):

First is one constant string which can't be modified. Second is an array with initialized value, so it can be modified.

Answer (score -1):

Segmentation fault is caused when you try to access the memory which is inaccessible.

`char *str` is a pointer to a string that is nonmodifiable(the reason for getting segfault).

whereas `char str[]` is an array and can be modifiable..

Answer (score -1):

This first one means something different than you think it does:

```
char *str = "string";
```

It means,

1. Store my string of characters -> "string"
2. at an address (which is picked by the compiler)
3. Save the address where "string" is stored in a variable named `str`.

Next, you try to *change the address* where your string "string" is stored:

```
str[0] = 'z';  // could be also written as *str = 'z'
```

**Try A Simple Program**

You can prove that this is true by simply altering your program a bit.

Try compiling and running the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *str = "string";
    // str[0] = 'z';  // could be also written as *str = 'z'
    // PRINT the value contained in str (it's an address - a pointer which points to "string")
    printf("%p\n", str); 
}
```

On my machine the result output is:
`0x55e789c1d004`

When you attempt to write to `str[0]` with str[0] = 'z' your attempting to store the address 'z' at the address  `0x55e789c1d004`